# Can't I float the elements to right and have them have the same width?

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm working on wrapping text using CSS but unfortunately for some reason i can't float them to the right instead they are overlapping each other. And also how can I give them a fix width so that they will have the same with and will align properly.

CHECK MY CODE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/g7C2v/

```
#simple_arc { 
                 border: 1px solid red; 
                 display: block; 
                 width:306px; 
                 height:305px;
                 }
```

Got stock with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

simply add `position:relative` to `<li>`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/g7C2v/1/)

```
li {
    float: left; 
    position:relative; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you've used `position:absolute` for each `span`, without any `relative` parent, they all are positioned relative to the body.

Just add `position:relative` to `#simple_arc`, `#reversed_arc` and `#auto_radius`

A cleaner code will be to add some `id` to `<ul>` and then using `#id li` -

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="container">
    <!-- Content -->
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
#container li {
    position: relative
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/niks999/TxfuT/)

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear : It seems you want to move each circles next to next ..Anyways u have used `absolute position` for each circle so u can use `left:some` values to each `li`.
like

```
#simple_arc { left: 0px; } 
#reversed_arc { left: 50px; } 
#auto_radius { left: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you.

CHECK THIS CODE:http://jsfiddle.net/g7C2v/3/

Comment: copy the http address.

Comment: this is link only answer, say what did you changed ?

Comment: just apply position relative nothing else.